# Deploying a silverligth web page from Visual Studio does not update the cache

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

this has been bothering me for a while now and I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

I have a silverlight business application developed in Visual studio 2012 Update 3. I have a deployment item which uses file share to deploy the solution files to a file server where the IIS is located.

However, after deployment when I try to open the page in Internet Explorer (and also in firefox) I get the old page. I think this may have something to do with the silverlight application beeing cached somewhere on the local computer. Does anyone know where this cache is located and is it possible to empty it?

I have tried emptying web browser cache using Internet Options -> Genereal -> Browsing History -> Delete, but this does not seem to help.

I have noticed that first time you navigate to a silverlight web page it loads a bit longer and you can see the silverlight loading symbol. This is something that I do not get when I navigate to the published page.

One would think that the silverlight application would detect if a new version is available and toss the old version.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been discussed in many other SO posts and on lots of other sites but the solution I like the best is discussed in this blog (and others)  [avoid-incorrect-caching-of-silverlight-xap-file](http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2010/02/avoid-incorrect-caching-of-silverlight-xap-file/)

It has both C# and VB versions of the code.  Basically, you change your web page that hosts the XAP to add a date to the name that gets passed to the browser. This way, each time the XAP changes, the browser KNOWS it is a different XAP and downloads it.

For posterity, here is what that link says:

*The code below appends the last-write filedate of the Silverlight Application XAP file to the path in the source parametre of the Silverlight object tag.
 This will ensure that poorly constructed caching functionality of webbrowsers and proxy servers doesn’t incorrectly use old, wrong builds of the XAP file.
 However it will still allow these caches to work. Furthermore a check is performed to avoid XAP file path alteration during debugging, this is to allow debugging tools such as Silverlight Spy to continue functioning.*

C#

```
<object id="Xaml1" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
<%––<param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApp.xap"/>––%>
<%
  string orgSourceValue = @"ClientBin/SilverlightApp.xap";
  string param;
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "\" />";
  else
  {
    string xappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"") + @"\" + orgSourceValue;
    DateTime xapCreationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(xappath);
    param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "?ignore=" + xapCreationDate.ToString() + "\" />";
  }
  Response.Write(param);
%>
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
```

VB

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
  <%--<param name="source" value="SpecialEntityMaint.xap"/>--%>
    <%
      Dim orgSourceValue As String = "SpecialEntityMaint.xap"
      Dim param As String
      If (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) Then
        param = "<param name=""source"" value=""" + orgSourceValue + """ />"
      Else
        Dim xappath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("") + "\" + orgSourceValue
        Dim xapCreationDate As DateTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(xappath)
        param = "<param name=""source"" value=""" + orgSourceValue + "?ignore=" + xapCreationDate.ToString() + """ />"
      End If

      Response.Write(param)
    %>
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
```